# OutOfMemoryError when displaying contacts' photos in Android (bitmap size exceeds VM budget)

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I use the following function to retrieve a contact's photo in Android where the person's lookup key is given:

```
public Bitmap getContactPhoto(String lookup_key) {
    Uri lookUpUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookup_key);
    Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(ctx.getContentResolver(), lookUpUri);
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), contentUri);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (stream != null) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bitmapOptions);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I display those contact photos in a list view, I sometimes read the following error in the developer console's crash reports:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=6023KB, Allocated=3002KB, Bitmap Size=27152KB)
```

Does this mean that my app may use about 3MB of heap but a single bitmap had roughly 27MB?

I read a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow concerning OutOfMemory error but it was mainly about:

- leaking contexts so that the garbage collector cannot free the resources
- huge bitmaps that need to be scaled

But how can I prevent the error in my case? Since I only get the contacts' photos, I don't know if I have huge bitmaps that must be scaled. And leaking a context doesn't seem to be the case here.

**This is how the images are displayed:**

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
if (<BITMAP_OBJECT> != null) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(<BITMAP_OBJECT>);
}
else {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
}
```

Comment: the issue is not related to what you are showing. Please attach code where the getContactPhoto() is called

Comment: do you call the last snippet you posted in some kind of Adapter

Comment: Yes, the last snippet is called in the iteration where the adapter rows are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting your `Bitmap` to an `ImageView`, try doing this:

```
Bitmap oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
oldBitmap.recycle();
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

It may not complete get rid of the problem, but it certainly makes it happen much more rarely.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried to implement this, the result of imageView.getDrawable() has no method getBitmap(). Additionally, isn't the error in my case that a single bitmap was too big?

Comment: You have to cast it to a `BitmapDrawable`. If you are setting `Bitmap`s to these `ImageView`s, then it's a safe cast.

Also, the underlying problem may simply be running out of memory. Sometimes these errors are deceptive. Worth a shot either way, and it's a good practice.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Unfortunately, I get the following runtime exception: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap." So recycling the adapter entries/rows seems not to be the solution.

Comment: Are you doing the 2nd line and setting the `ImageView`'s drawable to null before recycling? You get that error when recycling a `Bitmap` that is still in use, or is attempting to be used again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scaling your bitmap? Here is how you do it...

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2; // adjust sample size to whatever you want it to be

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        if ( bitmap != null && exact ) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, width, height, false );
        }
```

Here in the method `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`, I create a scaled `Bitmap` so that it consumes lesser memory than it did before, it solved my problem, what about yours?